# Typedef, or alias, or something for std::chrono::duration_cast for easier typing

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef

This is, most probably, a simple question, but I don't know how to do it. How can `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>()` be used with `typedef`, or `std::function`, or anything else? I can't use `using std::chrono`, I tried to make a pointer to a function, but when I looked over [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast), I get dizzy, plus all the codes I see use `auto`, which doesn't help.

Comment: You just want `using std::chrono::duration_cast;` and maybe `using std::chrono::microseconds;`? Or `using namespace std::chrono;`?

Comment: I can `typedef` the `microseconds`, and the `high_resolution_clock`, but not `duration_cast`. If I could use the `using...`, I wouldn't need any of these.

Comment: Is something like `using dc = std::chrono::duration_cast;` what you are after?

Comment: Why can you not use `using ...`??

Comment: @walnut I don't know, it complained about "you can't use with `std::chrono`", I said OK...

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Then please ask about the error message instead of making unreasonable requirements from what you *think* you need. You just have the wrong syntax. I gave you the correct one in my first comment.

Comment: @walnut I am sorry, but when I tried it, gcc complained about not naming a type (or something similar). I would rather use `typedef` for easier typing, though, `using ...` would be a second choice, but I'll take it if there's nothing else.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Please ask about the error message. Show your code and the error message in your question and we can tell you what you did wrong. `typedef` is not a solution if `using` doesn't work. `using` can do everything that `typedef` can.

Comment: @walnut I tried replicating what I did and it looks like I simply forgot to add `namespace` in `using`, that must have been it. Still, the answers below work for me, in particular Marek's. This is preferable over the `using ...` part, because I can write now `micro()`, or `milli()`, instead of the whole thing, all over the source. I only need to measure some mini functions that will be called millions of times inside others, and even as a beginner (as I know I am), I need to do it -- and I'd rather not waste too much time typing than timing. My apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. it depends what exactly you are trying to achieve.

One way to approach this is define own helper function (in own namespace or global):

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::chrono::microseconds asMicroseconds(T duration)
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(duration);
}
```

Comment: This does it very nice for me, thank you. I'll wait a while before marking it down, though.

Answer (score 1):

Do not know if this is what you wanted but:

```
    auto asMicroseconds = [](auto x){return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(x);};
```

Seems to be working fine

Comment: `(auto&& x)` would stop you from making a copy.

Comment: @NathanOliver for duration there is no gain.